# differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign] disable this check in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I have a open source C project, I have imported that project in to eclipse and compiled .
I get many warnings related to differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign] . I want to disable this warnings in the eclipse .

I added the flag -Wpointer-sign, in the eclipse c/c++ build settings Miscellaneous, but I still get this warnings .

How to avoid this warnings ..

Comment: Use `-Wno-pointer-sign` to disable the warning. `-Wpointer-sign` actually enables that warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **-Wno-pointer-sign**. You can find it in `man gcc`